# Вычитание числа из БД

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать, чтобы можно было вычесть -1 в бд одним запросом sql.

Хотел сделать так, но вспомнил, что можно одним запросом вычитать.

```
$x = '100';
$y = '50';
$z = $x-$y;

INSERT INTO БД SET money='$z' WHERE id='1'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Используется обычный минус http://coderlearner.com/Mysql_operator_MINUS. Да, еще оператор insert написан неверно. http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html

**Обновление**

1. По поводу insert: `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3);`
2. По поводу минуса: `INSERT INTO table SET x="$x", y="$y", z=x-y;`
3. `WHERE` в `INSERT` вставлять нельзя, если это не `INSERT SELECT`.

Comment: А можно скрипт, пожалуйста. Там не понятно ничего.

Comment: По поводу insert: INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3);

По поводу минуса: INSERT INTO table SET x="$x", y="$y", z=x-y;

WHERE в INSERT вставлять нельзя, если это не INSERT SELECT.

Comment: Нет. Это не то. Там sql функция какая то. Без калькулятора вообще, просто стоит функция и -1

Comment: Как я понял, не INSERT, а UPDATE.

UPDATE БД SET x=x-1 Where ...

Без Where декрементируются все записи.